# Validating a form with a dynamic name inside directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
<form name="{{ formname }}" novalidate>
    <input type="text" ng-model="first_name" required>
    <input type="text" ng-model="last_name" required>
    <input type="text" ng-model="email" required>
    <span class="error" ng-show="formname.$invalid">Fill in required fields.</span>
    <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

I'm trying to validate the form using Angular's built in validation but because the formname is set dynamically by text passed in from the scope I'm not sure how to call it. This attempt above doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a little help from the controller. Define another variable (`f` in the example below), watch `formname` and update `f` accordingly:

```
.controller("...", function($scope) {
    $scope.first_name = "";
    $scope.formname = "fff";
    $scope.f = null;
    $scope.$watch("formname",function(newval,oldval,scope) {
        scope.f = scope[newval];
    });
});
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T7vuD/

Comment: Yes, it is workaround-ish. By -ish I mean I do not think there is a straightforward way of doing it (in other words there will be nothing *but* workarounds for this problem). As a matter of fact, at first I though that doing simply `ng-show="[formname].$invalid"` would work (i.e. implicitly evaluate `$scope[formname]`). It didn't.